# How do you scan a QR code inside a modal with React?

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, qr-code, virtual-dom

So I've been using `react-qr-barcode-scanner` and it's working fine.

I have a react component which is this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState} from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { useHistory, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import BarcodeScannerComponent from "react-qr-barcode-scanner";

const QR = () => {
  const [data, setData ] = useState('Not Found');
  const history = useHistory();
  useEffect(() => {
    if(data === 'Not Found') {
        return;
    }

    history.push(data);
    history.go();
})
    return (

    <>
        <BarcodeScannerComponent
            width={500}
            height={500}
            onUpdate={(err, result) => {
                if (result) {
                    setData(result.text);
                }
                else setData("Not Found");
            }}

        />
        <p>{data}</p>
    </>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#qr-modal">
        <i class="fas fa-qrcode"></i>
    </button>
        <div class="modal fade" id="qr-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <QR />
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('qr-id')
);
```

Notice that I render the button and the modal aswell, this doesn't work, however, If I just render the QR component, it works fine although I need a button/modal action for my implementation. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: u should import bootstrap

Comment: It's importing the modal is working fine, the problem is QR code is not being scanned.

Comment: Im doing a redirect after QR is being scanned. And this works fine ```without``` modal

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what isn't working? The two `history` navigations also seem wrong. Where are you redirecting to? `useEffect` hook is missing dependency array.

Comment: Basically the scanner seems inactive, no matter how long I hold my QR code against the camera it doesn't do anything. If I cut the modal part out, it work's perfectly, it scans and it redirects me the to the scanned URL.

Comment: bootstrap-modal has a fade-in time of 350 ms, which you should "await". To test if this is where things go wrong, please remove `fade` class from `div#qr-modal` and let me know if that works.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the tip, unfortunately, it still doesn't scan my QR code.

Comment: Can you update the code in your question to provide enough of a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I tried reproducing it locally but I guess I'm not getting all the correct bootstrap-modal CSS/JS in the correct places.

Comment: So after days of trial and error, I got it to work by using react-modal. I'm guessing there was some sort of discrepancy because I was using bootstrap modal which works with Jquery, and my bet is that react didn't know that the modal was set to visible. weird bug anyhow. Thanks.